# Is it possible to trigger service bus processors when the client object is disposed?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-sdk-.net

I am calling ServiceBusClient.DisposeAsync for disposing the client object. However, there are processors created from this object which starts throwing an exception saying the object is disposed and it cannot listen anymore. Is there any way to trigger auto closure of service processors when dispose is called? Or, should I get hold of all the processors created from this client and then stop the listening?

Comment: In a situation where there is a mandate to create service bus client using a sas token which is issued only for a short period of time, I need to get a new Sas Token and then re-generate the ServiceBusClient object. In this situation, I have to make sure I close the existing processors and dispose the SBClient created with the previous token. Right?

Comment: You do not need to regenerate the Service Bus clients to rotate a SAS token.  You can do so in-place using the `AzureSasCredential`.   It offers an `Update` method that allows the SAS to be rotated and automatically picked up by the associated clients.   More information:  https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.azuresascredential?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: If I created the ServiceBusClient using an inline like the below, there is no way to update it, right? I need to declare the AzureSasCredentials somewhere outside and then update it when needed. Once I do that sbClient will update its connection.
            ServiceBusClient sbClient = new ServiceBusClient(serviceBusNamespace, new Azure.AzureSasCredential(sasToken)
                , this.GetServiceBusClientOptions()
                );

Comment: Correct; you'd need to hang onto a reference to the credential so that you could interact with it for updates.

Comment: Should this be an enhancement to the SDK to allow access to the SasCredential object by pulling it from the client object? :) something like - ServiceBusClient.AzureSasCredential.
Or will this be a security concern?

Comment: @JesseSquire: Is it ok to Update the Sas credential when the processor is actively listening and i have a sender currently sending? Or should I update AzureSasCredential after closing the senders and stopping the receivers? Could you please throw some light?

Comment: It is safe to update while things are running.   The new value gets swapped in and used the next time auth is sent.

Comment: @JesseSquire: I see that sender.IsClosed is "false" when its SbClient.IsClosed is "true". What are the ways SbClient.IsClosed can become "true" other than me invoking sbclient.Dispose?   I believe SbClient cannot be revived once we dispose it. I am asking this so that the senders can be left alone while I revive the SBClient. If it's not possible, then I will need to dispose the sender also and recreate the sender with the new client.

Comment: The sender is not closed until you ask it to do so; calling CloseAsync or DisposeAsync are how you'd do so.   If you close/dispose your client, you're signaling that you're done with it.  The state is final and you cannot "bring it back to life".    Because the client owns the shared connection, closing/disposing it will invalidate the connection used by any child objects that spawn from it.   Generally, we do not advise closing/disposing a client until you've completed using all child objects associated with it.   Disposing the client is not meant to be a kill signal to its children.

Comment: @JesseSquire: I have an observation.  This was to understand the dynamics of the processor. Inside the ProcessMessageAsync method, I issued processor StopProcessingAsync followed by DisposeAsync. I could see that the IsProcessing is true(until I exit the method) but IsClosed is also true. How is the AutoComplete happening if the connection is closed? I understand that the AutoComplete removes the message after the ProcessingMethod exists but while exiting I had disposed the processor. This is to understand and not the actual implementation though.

Comment: The connection is owned by the client; stopping a processor does not close the connection.   When the processor is stopped, it will eagerly mark itself as closed to prevent new operations from being started and will allow operations already in-flight to complete.   Note that awaiting StopProcessingAsync in the handler is NOT recommended; it will very likely deadlock your code.    (as documented in remarks here: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusprocessor.processmessageasync?view=azure-dotnet#remarks)

Comment: @JesseSquire: Thanks for the details and pointers to the documentation. Yes, during my tests when I awaited StopProcessingAsync the code went into deadlock.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no; there is intentionally no "stop processing on dispose" behavior for the processor.  Your application is responsible for calling `StopProcessingAsync`.

**More context:**

The `ServiceBusClient` owns the connection shared by all child objects spawned from it.  Closing/disposing the client will effectively dispose its children.   If you attempt to invoke a service operation at that point, an error is triggered.

In the case of a processor, the application holds responsibility for calling start and stop.  Because the processor is designed to be resilient, its goal is to continue to recover in the face of failures and keep trying to make forward progress until stop is called.

While it's true that the processor does understand that a disposed set of network resources is terminal, it has no way to understand your intent.  Did your application close the `ServiceBusClient` with the intent that it would stop the associated processors?   Did it close the client without realizing that there were processors still running?

Because the intent is ambiguous, we have to take the safer path.  The processors will continue to run because they'll surface the exceptions to your application's error handler - which ensures that your application is made aware that there is an issue and allows you to respond in the way best for your application's needs.

On the other hand, if processing just stopped and you did not intend for that to happen, it would be much harder for your application to detect and remediate.  You would just know that the processor stopped doing its job and there's a good chance that you wouldn't be able to understand why without a good deal of investigation.